# JavaFX: Why HBox does not arrange controls in a single horizontal row? How to work arround this bug and make HBox do what is supposed to do?

Tags: java, javafx

HBox is a container component meant to keep and arrange controls within a single horizontal line. However, I experience a "chaotic" placement of controls in one of many HBox containers in my app and the placement definitely does not resemble a horizontal line, moreover, controls wrapped within the HBox mess about other controls which are not included in the HBox.

A placement looks fine in SceneBuilder, it looks fine even in the SceneBuilder preview window, however, it differs when FXML loaded into my app. My code does not contain any position modifications - all is rendered and placed exactly where it is supposed to be according fo FXML file, except for several controls from the problematic HBox.

The app design and the SceneBuilder preview looks like this:

[image: SceneBuilder design of my app and SceneBuilder preview]

All is displayed as expected and corresponds to FXML structure.

However, when FXML loaded in my app, one of the HBox displays a chaos (although its structure within FXML is similar to a HBox above, which displays OK):

[image: Real application based on the FXML with a chaotic placement of controls]

There are some things above my head:

- How HBox can arrange controls vertically instead of horizontally?
- How other controls (a textfield), not included in a HBox, may display BETWEEN controls wrapped within HBox?
- How can preview in SceneBuilder seem differently from the real app? Is the preview a matter of a different interpretation of a FXML than in JavaFX runtime in my app?
- Why some of the HBox work fine and other do not, when having (almost) the same structure in FXML (the problem with the HBox persists even when I reuse /copy+paste/ the HBox above which works fine).

I was googling on existing bugs in HBox and JavaFX, but did not find anything that might help to fix this problem. I have even no idea how I could straighten this mess from my code.

**How can I prevent this from happening or fix or at least work arround?** Thanks anyone for any advice!

My FXML is here (I omitted a content of the other tab for this post):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="rootAnchorPane" maxHeight="400.0" maxWidth="650.0" minHeight="400.0" minWidth="650.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="650.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cz.oksystem.oksmart3calc.gui.OKsmart3CalculatorController">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="650.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="650.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="650.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="340.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <HBox maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="530.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="530.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="530.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="chipImage" disable="true" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@/image_chip.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <viewport>
                        <Rectangle2D height="40.0" width="46.0" />
                     </viewport>
                  </ImageView>
                  <VBox>
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="calcTitle" maxWidth="470.0" minWidth="470.0" prefWidth="470.0" text="OKsmart 3 Calculator" textFill="#009646">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
                           </font>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="1.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Label>
                        <Label fx:id="statusLineLabel" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="470.0" minWidth="470.0" prefWidth="470.0" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <RadioButton fx:id="langCeskyRadioBtn" maxWidth="70.0" minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onKeyReleased="#langCeskyRadioBtnKeySelected" onMouseClicked="#langCeskyRadioBtnMouseSelected" prefWidth="70.0" selected="true" text="Česky">
                           <toggleGroup>
                              <ToggleGroup fx:id="langRadioBtnGroup" />
                           </toggleGroup>
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="10.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="2.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@/vlajka_cr_21.png" />
                           </image>
                           <viewport>
                              <Rectangle2D height="13.0" width="21.0" />
                           </viewport>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <RadioButton fx:id="langAnglickyRadioBtn" maxWidth="70.0" minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onKeyReleased="#langAnglickyRadioBtnKeySelected" onMouseClicked="#langAnglickyRadioBtnMouseSelected" prefWidth="70.0" text="Anglicky" toggleGroup="$langRadioBtnGroup">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="5.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@/vlajka_en_21.png" />
                           </image>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="2.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                           <viewport>
                              <Rectangle2D height="13.0" width="21.0" />
                           </viewport>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" right="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <TabPane fx:id="calculatorTabPane" layoutY="60.0" maxHeight="340.0" maxWidth="650.0" minHeight="340.0" minWidth="650.0" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="650.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="60.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="unblockCardTab" closable="false" onSelectionChanged="#unblockTabSelected" text="Odblokování karty">
               <content>
                  <VBox fx:id="uc_unblockTabVBox" maxHeight="310.0" maxWidth="650.0" minHeight="310.0" minWidth="650.0" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="650.0">
                     <children>
                        <HBox maxWidth="650.0" minWidth="650.0" prefWidth="650.0">
                           <children>
                              <VBox fx:id="uc_labelsVBox" maxWidth="220.0" minWidth="220.0" prefWidth="220.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_unblockTypeLabel" text="Způsob odblokování:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="8.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="10.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_ublockKeyLabel" text="Klíč pro odblokování:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="8.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_challengeLabel" text="Výzva (challenge):">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="8.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_serialNoLabel" text="Sériové číslo karty (UID):">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="8.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_pwdKeyStoreLabel" text="Heslo úložiště klíčů pro odblokování:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="8.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_cardReaderLabel" text="Čtečka karet:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="7.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_newPinLabel" text="Nový PIN:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="7.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="uc_newPinVerifyLabel" text="Ověření nového PINu:">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets bottom="7.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </Label>
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                              <VBox fx:id="uc_controlsVBox" maxWidth="430.0" minWidth="430.0" prefWidth="430.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <HBox maxWidth="415.0" minWidth="415.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                       <children>
                                          <RadioButton fx:id="uc_remoteRadioBtn" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="205.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="205.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onKeyReleased="#uc_remoteRadioBtnKeySelect" onMouseClicked="#uc_remoteRadioBtnMouseClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="205.0" selected="true" text="Vzdálené (výpočet odezvy)">
                                             <toggleGroup>
                                                <ToggleGroup fx:id="uc_radioBtnGroup" />
                                             </toggleGroup>
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </RadioButton>
                                          <RadioButton fx:id="uc_localRadioBtn" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="205.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="205.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onKeyReleased="#uc_localRadioBtnKeySelect" onMouseClicked="#uc_localRadioBtnMouseClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="Lokální (máte k dispozici kartu)" toggleGroup="$uc_radioBtnGroup">
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </RadioButton>
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                    <ChoiceBox fx:id="uc_keyChoiceBox" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="415.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="415.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </ChoiceBox>
                                    <TextField fx:id="uc_challengeTextField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="415.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="415.0" onKeyReleased="#uc_challengeTextFieldChanged" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </TextField>
                                    <TextField fx:id="uc_serialNoTextField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="415.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="415.0" onKeyReleased="#uc_serialNoTextFieldChanged" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </TextField>
                                    <HBox fx:id="uc_pwdHbox">
                                       <children>
                                          <PasswordField fx:id="uc_pwdKeyStorePwdField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="385.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="385.0" onKeyReleased="#uc_pwdKeyStorePwdFieldChanged" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="385.0">
                                             <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </VBox.margin>
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </PasswordField>
                                          <Button fx:id="uc_pwdPreviewButton" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="25.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMousePressed="#uc_previewPwdButtonMousePressed" onMouseReleased="#uc_previewPwdButtonMouseReleased" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                                             <graphic>
                                                <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                                   <image>
                                                      <Image url="@/eye-simple.png" />
                                                   </image>
                                                   <viewport>
                                                      <Rectangle2D height="20.0" width="20.0" />
                                                   </viewport>
                                                </ImageView>
                                             </graphic>
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </Button>
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                    <ChoiceBox fx:id="uc_cardReaderChoiceBox" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="415.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="415.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </ChoiceBox>
                                    <HBox>
                                       <children>
                                          <PasswordField fx:id="uc_newPinPwdField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="385.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="385.0" onKeyReleased="#uc_newPinTextFieldChanged" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="385.0">
                                             <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </VBox.margin>
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </PasswordField>
                                       </children>
                                       <VBox.margin>
                                          <Insets />
                                       </VBox.margin>
                                    </HBox>
                                    <HBox fx:id="uc_pwdHbox1">
                                       <children>
                                          <PasswordField fx:id="uc_newPinVerifyPwdField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="385.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="385.0" onKeyReleased="#uc_newPinVerifyTextFieldChanged" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="385.0" promptText="preview">
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                             <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </VBox.margin>
                                          </PasswordField>
                                          <Button fx:id="uc_pwdPreviewButton1" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="25.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMousePressed="#uc_previewPwdButtonMousePressed" onMouseReleased="#uc_previewPwdButtonMouseReleased" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" text="P">
                                             <HBox.margin>
                                                <Insets right="10.0" top="5.0" />
                                             </HBox.margin>
                                          </Button>
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <VBox maxWidth="650.0" minWidth="650.0" prefWidth="650.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="170.0" minWidth="170.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="170.0" minWidth="170.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="2.0" valignment="TOP" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="25.0" minHeight="25.0" prefHeight="25.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
                                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="5.0" valignment="BOTTOM" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="uc_unblockButton" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="310.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onKeyReleased="#uc_unblockButtonKeyFired" onMouseClicked="#uc_unblockButtonMouseClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="310.0" text="Vypočíst odezvu" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                    <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </GridPane>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <HBox fx:id="uc_responseHBox" maxWidth="650.0" minWidth="650.0" prefWidth="650.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="uc_responseLabel" prefWidth="210.0" text="Odezva (response):">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="5.0" top="8.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <TextField fx:id="uc_responseTextField" maxHeight="25.0" maxWidth="415.0" minHeight="25.0" minWidth="415.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="415.0">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="10.0" right="5.0" top="2.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </TextField>
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="keyStoreTab" closable="false" onSelectionChanged="#keyStoreTabSelected" text="Správa klíčů pro odblokování">
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My code for loading is here:

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
              getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cz/oksystem/oksmart3calc/gui/OKsmart3Calculator.fxml"),
              OKsmart3CalculatorController.messages);
      AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(
              getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cz/oksystem/oksmart3calc/gui/application.css").toExternalForm());
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setTitle("OKsmart 3 Calculator");
      primaryStage.show();
      primaryStage.setResizable(false);
      primaryStage.sizeToScene();
      Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
      final OKsmart3CalculatorController oksmart3CalculatorController = (OKsmart3CalculatorController) fxmlLoader
              .getController();
      primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
          boolean neededConfirmation = oksmart3CalculatorController.deleteUnsavedRecordsConfirmation(event);
          if (!neededConfirmation || oksmart3CalculatorController.isConfirmedByUser()) {
            oksmart3CalculatorController.saveSettings();
            oksmart3CalculatorController.cardManagerProviderShutdown();
            Platform.exit();
          }
          event.consume();
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you also share a part of the controller code? so that it is possible to try it

Comment: Agreed: in general, can you make this so others can reproduce it (i.e. post a [MCVE]?). I spent a considerable time editing your code (removing references to the controller and the image resources etc) so that I could at least execute it, and then could not reproduce any problems.

Comment: Other than that, I guess the only comment I can see to make with the code you've posted is that I don't really understand the layout choices you made. I don't really see how the labels on the left of the tab are aligning vertically with the controls: isn't this just by chance? If you change the font, or just display on a machine with different fonts available, I don't see how you guarantee everything stays lined up (though I may be missing something). A more natural approach here would be a single grid pane with 10 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: As James_D points out, you should use a GridPane, which is by far the most appropriate layout for label/field rows.  Some of your right-hand areas should still be HBoxes, but you should remove all min/max/pref width/height settings.  Let the controls determine their own sizes.  If you want your TextFields to be a certain width, set their [prefColumnCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#prefColumnCountProperty) properties instead.

Comment: @VGR Actually, I'd just use a grid pane, no `HBox`es on the right. The problem with using `HBox`es there is that you can't really get those buttons on the right (next to the password fields) to line up vertically without hard-coding some sizes. With a grid pane you can. Just use column spans for some of the controls. Labels all in col0, those two radio buttons in the first row are col1, {col2, col3}, the choice box below is {col1, col2, col3}, next row has password field in {col1, col2} and button in col3, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your comments. I eventually realized a possible cause of the behaviour I described, then I confirmed it experimentally and fixed.

When I claimed that I do not modify position of the controls in my code, it was a half-truth. I dynamically remove and add controls from and into their parents, depending on state of radiobuttons on the top, because not all the controls have sense together. Swithing between radiobuttons "Lokální" (Local) and "Vzdálené" (Remote) changes a configuration of the controls below - some of the appear while other disapper depending on the choice of Local vs. Remote, which is a desired behaviour. I provide snippets of code in my controller class below (after a fix):

```
  @FXML
  public void uc_remoteRadioBtnMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Vzdalene mys...");
    setVisibleRemoteUnblockControls(Key.KeyType.ADMIN_MASTER_KEY);
  };

  @FXML
  public void uc_localRadioBtnMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Lokalni mys...");
    setVisibleLocalUnblockControls();
  };

  @FXML
  public void uc_remoteRadioBtnKeySelect(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Vzdalene klavesa...");
    setVisibleRemoteUnblockControls(Key.KeyType.ADMIN_STATIC_KEY);
  };

  @FXML
  public void uc_localRadioBtnKeySelect(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Lokalni klavesa...");
    setVisibleLocalUnblockControls();
  };

  private void setVisibleRemoteUnblockControls(Key.KeyType keyType) {
    if (!uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_challengeLabel))
      uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_challengeLabel);
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_challengeTextField))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_challengeTextField);
    if (keyType.equals(Key.KeyType.ADMIN_STATIC_KEY)) {

      uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_serialNoLabel);
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_serialNoTextField);
    } else {
      if (!uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_serialNoLabel))
        uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_serialNoLabel);
      if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_serialNoTextField))
        uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_serialNoTextField);
    }
    uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_cardReaderLabel);
    uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_newPinLabel);
    uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_newPinVerifyLabel);
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_cardReaderChoiceBox);
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_pinHBox);
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_pinVerifyHBox);

    this.uc_unblockButton.setText(
            this.uc_remoteRadioBtn.isSelected() ? messages.getString("OKsmart3Calculator.uc_unblockButtonRemote")
                    : messages.getString("OKsmart3Calculator.uc_unblockButtonLocal"));
    if (!uc_unblockTabVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_responseHBox))
      uc_unblockTabVBox.getChildren().add(uc_responseHBox);
    if (true) {
      printInfoStatus("Zadejte heslo, výzvu a vypočtěte odezvu.");
    }

    this.settingsStore.setProperty(UC_LOCALRADIOBTN, Boolean.valueOf(this.uc_localRadioBtn.isSelected()).toString());
  }

  private void setVisibleLocalUnblockControls() {
    uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_challengeLabel);
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_challengeTextField);
    uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_serialNoLabel);
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_serialNoTextField);
    if (!uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_cardReaderLabel))
      uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_cardReaderLabel);
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_cardReaderChoiceBox))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_cardReaderChoiceBox);
    if (!uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_newPinLabel))
      uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_newPinLabel);
    if (!uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_newPinVerifyLabel))
      uc_labelsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_newPinVerifyLabel);
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_pinHBox))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_pinHBox);
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_pinVerifyHBox))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_pinVerifyHBox);

    this.uc_unblockButton.setText(
            this.uc_remoteRadioBtn.isSelected() ? messages.getString("OKsmart3Calculator.uc_unblockButtonRemote")
                    : messages.getString("OKsmart3Calculator.uc_unblockButtonLocal"));
    uc_unblockTabVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_responseHBox);
    if (true) {
      printErrorStatus("Vložte kartu do čtečky...");
    }

    this.settingsStore.setProperty(UC_LOCALRADIOBTN, Boolean.valueOf(this.uc_localRadioBtn.isSelected()).toString());

  }
```

The problem occured when I wrapped `uc_newPinVerifyPwdField` into a new `uc_pinVerifyHBox`, but forgot to modify the original code for adding/removing `uc_newPinVerifyPwdField` to/from its parent. Originally tha parent for `uc_newPinVerifyPwdField` was `uc_controlsVBox`, however, `uc_newPinVerifyPwdField` is not child of `uc_controlsVBox` anymore - it became a child of `uc_pinVerifyHBox`. The code looked originally (before fix) like this:

```
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_newPinVerifyPwdField);
```

and

```
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_newPinVerifyPwdField))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_newPinVerifyPwdField);
```

instead of the current, correct:

```
    uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().remove(uc_pinVerifyHBox);
```

and

```
    if (!uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().contains(uc_pinVerifyHBox))
      uc_controlsVBox.getChildren().add(uc_pinVerifyHBox);
```

It seems, it had caused the chaos in rendering of the controls, which now works like OK.